# Trouble using dup2 to redirect stdout/stderr into the same file

Tags: c, linux, dup2

I'm having some trouble using `dup2` in trying to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` into the same output file.

I'm using this explanatory code sample: (gcc 4.8.2, Ubuntu 14.04)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USE2FILES

int main()
{
    int f1, f2, status;

    f1 = open("test.out", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    if (f1 == -1) {
        perror("open(): ");
    }
    status = dup2(f1, STDOUT_FILENO);
    if (status == -1) {
        perror("dup2(): ");
    }

#ifdef USE2FILES
    close(f1);
#endif

#ifdef USE2FILES
    f2 = open("test.out", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    if (f2 == -1) {
        perror("dup2(): ");
    }
#else
    f2 = f1;
#endif
    status = dup2(f2, STDERR_FILENO);
    if (status == -1) {
        perror("dup2(): ");
    }
    close(f2);

    fprintf(stderr, "test_stderr1\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "test_stdout1\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "test_stderr2\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "test_stdout2\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "test_stderr3\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "test_stdout3\n");

    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);

    return 0;
}
```

USE2FILES macro is supposed to switch between using either 2 file descriptors (to the same file) which get duped to `stdout` and `stderr` respectivly or 1 file descriptor which gets duplicated both to `stdout` and `stderr`.

I was under the impression that using 2 distinct file descriptors for redirection should work. However running this piece of code with USE2FILES on issues the following output in `test.out`:

```
test_stdout1
test_stdout2
test_stdout3
```

If I then disable USE2FILES I get:

```
test_stderr1
test_stderr2
test_stderr3
test_stdout1
test_stdout2
test_stdout3
```

Seems like in the first case no output towards `stderr` gets through. Is this behavior to be expected (am I missing something)?

**EDIT**: After accepted Chris Dodd's answer:
That's indeed a poor example. Changing the `fprintf` sequence to something like this:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "test_stderr+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++1\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "test_stdout----------------------------------------1\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "test_stderr++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++2\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "test_stdout----------------2\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "test_stderr++++++++++++++++++++++++++++3\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "test_stdout----------------------3\n");
```

gets me this `test.out` output:

```
test_stdout----------------------------------------1
test_stdout----------------2
test_stdout----------------------3
err++++++++++++++++++++++++++++3
```

showing pretty clearly `stdout` & `stderr` are competing with their writes over the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do two `open` calls, you get two distinct kernel filehandles, each with its own I/O cursor (file offset), so writes to the two file descriptors will overwrite each other.  If you use a single `open` call, you only get a single filehandle that both file descriptors refer to, so each write (to each descriptor) will advance the output offset so the next write (with the other file descriptor) will write after it.

In your example, the strings written are the exact same length, so the write to `stdout` exactly overwrites the preceeding write to `stderr`.  Note that the file write only occurs when the `FILE` object is flushed, not (necessarily) when `fprintf` is called.

You could also get the effect you seem to be trying to get by opening the files in `O_APPEND` mode.  This will cause every write to reposition the write offset to the current end of the file just before actually writing.